# combine several arrays which produce as an output in to a single one

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

Here my outcome looks like this, please have a look

```
array(4) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(5) "12:00" 
    [1]=> string(5) "12:20" 
    [2]=> string(5) "12:40" 
    [3]=> string(5) "01:00" 
} 
array(2) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(5) "02:00" 
    [1]=> string(5) "02:20" 
}
```

Here is my code

```
   $t_i=$this->Hospital_model
             ->get_time_interval_break_split(
                     $t_i_b->start,
                     $t_i_b->end,
                     $consult_time);
$output =array_merge($t_i);
```

Here is my model

```
public function get_time_interval_break_split($start_time,$end_time,$consult_time)
{
   $array = array();
   $time_diff = $consult_time * 60;
   if(!empty($start_time))
   {
      for ($i=strtotime($start_time); $i<=strtotime($end_time); $i += $time_diff)
      {  
         $array[] = date("h:i", $i);
      } 
   }

   return $array;

 }
```

now i want to combine those two arrays in to one and i had used `array_map`,`array_merge` and all but didn't got a solution,please help me to solve

Comment: What did you try and didn't work for you?

Comment: Can you paste instead of a var_dump, a `json_encode`? That way we can play with the data

Comment: `$output =array_merge($t_i);` nice atempt. Array_merge generally works best with a minimum of two arrays.

Comment: @Andreas i know that but i didn't get any other way and i had used another way like this `$output +=$t_i` but didn't got

Comment: this function seems to return a single array and not 2 arrays. Can you post a var_dump of  `$output` ?

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou sure here it is `array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "12:00" [1]=> string(5) "12:20" [2]=> string(5) "12:40" [3]=> string(5) "01:00" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "02:00" [1]=> string(5) "02:20" }`

Comment: sorry i meant a var_dump of `$t_i `

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou var_dump of  `$t_i` is similar to `$output`

Answer (score 0):

Do it as below.

```
$a= array("12:00","12:20","12:40","01:00");
$b= array("02:00","02:20");

$merge = array_merge($a, $b);

var_dump($merge);
```